# Best way to bring up you real name, after fake has been used

Tags: awkward-situations, europe

Some months ago I joined a website because I wanted to get better at a certain skill. As happens so often, for the registering I had to give a name, and since I didn't know back then how visible my name will be from outside that community, I first gave a fake name.

Usually I don't interact much, if at all, with other people online, so it is usually not a problem. However in that case, one of the people in the community has contacted me to congratulate me on my achievements. And then we kept messaging each other. Since the only name he has is my pseudonym, he has greeted me using that.

However I now want to change to my real name (which wont be visible to people outside the community, I checked that). What I don't know is how can I best update that person on my real name, without making it awkward? We are both from central Europe.

Comment: What have you thought of doing, and why do you think that would be awkward? Without that, answers here would basically be just telling you 'what to say' (which is listed as being off-topic in the [help/on-topic]), and your questions isn't really asking about an Interpersonal Skill (behavior you use while interacting) so much as just 'things to say'. What part of your behavior when doing this are you struggling with, that you think would turn things awkward?

Comment: I have thought on bring it up with a justification on why I use a pseudonym, but my gut feeling tells me that would possibly be too much. It also implies that it was bad I used another name than mine as pseudonym. At the same time, having let that guy use my pseudonym without correcting him, feels like I have been lying by omission. On the other hand I know that I tend to overthink situations, so I wanted some help to avoid making this situation awkward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People do this on my Discord server pretty regularly. They change their nickname or display name to their real name, and make a small announcement in the appropriate channel (which for us is #welcome.) Something like:

> I've decided to use my real name here on this server with all you lovely people. Hello, I'm RealName. Still the same person as OldName.

You could do something similar, and perhaps share links to that with the person you've been dm-ing with. It's not uncommon and it's not a big deal.

If your website doesn't have channels, but does have "sigs" you could change yours to including "RealName, formerly posting here as OldName" for a while. You could dm a handful of people a message like the one I suggested above.

DO NOT apologize for your old name, use the word "fake", and so on. Pseudonyms online are used for a huge number of reasons and are not bad. Don't talk like they are.